# Десереализация XML ответа от SOAP

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Есть сторонний SOAP сервис. который возвращает ответ  виде XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <NS1:GetCarsByDateResponse xmlns:NS1="urn:scale_controllerIntf-Iscale_controller" xmlns:NS2="urn:scale_controllerIntf">
         <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:TCar[12]">
            <item href="#1"/>
            <item href="#2"/>
            <item href="#3"/>
            <item href="#4"/>
            <item href="#5"/>
            <item href="#6"/>
            <item href="#7"/>
            <item href="#8"/>
            <item href="#9"/>
            <item href="#10"/>
            <item href="#11"/>
            <item href="#12"/>
         </return>
         <NS2:TCar id="1" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">1</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">17C4EFA4-2274-48E8-93D9-B4994891ED52</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:46:32.845+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">00001</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">80</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">50</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">595.7</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">88</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">528.59</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">583.57</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="2" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">1</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">073C4A02-BCDC-48F1-BD44-DABB918C5A79</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:44:02.969+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">00002</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">80</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">50</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">598.62</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">88</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">536.1</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">502.67</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="3" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">7859FF3C-9FB3-40AA-8C89-77E7523F8638</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:00.152+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">80476945</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.1</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.1</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">577.81</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.1</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">560.56</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">513.9</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="4" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">A3CE7FAF-3F61-470E-8AEE-71A13117B2F6</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:06.053+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">87502662</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.2</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.2</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">511.26</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.2</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">587.58</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">588.43</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="5" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">9ED3EB3E-3AA5-43B4-9249-34A3366D5AEB</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:08.208+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">59989533</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.3</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.3</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">564.89</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.3</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">508.02</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">569.32</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="6" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">545B9A0C-341E-47B1-8AF3-C7B2E9E94F91</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:09.784+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">75903676</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.4</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.4</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">579.36</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.4</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">588.14</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">515.3</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="7" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">2ADF7FCC-3ECC-4EA8-80B9-902E5D879D93</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:11.260+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">78537392</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.5</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.5</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">530.41</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.5</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">545.54</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">595.16</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="8" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">7AE7A081-473D-42F1-ABE1-3DD42828A86A</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:12.757+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">40896853</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.6</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.6</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">570.03</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.6</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">503.41</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">559.64</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="9" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">8744B761-3EE4-48F3-8B08-DB2C3464BE43</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:13.935+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">45805685</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.7</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.7</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">566.37</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.7</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">559.81</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">537.07</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="10" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">0EDB8393-E095-4CE9-B6E4-727ACC927DC3</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:15.251+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">93915283</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.8</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.8</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">526.54</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.8</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">567.1</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">595.5</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="11" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">4FBDB8A8-9D88-4F69-ABCE-B5C74520693B</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:16.784+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">31218435</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">70.9</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">90.9</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">515.26</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">22.9</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">507.96</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">544.73</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
         <NS2:TCar id="12" xsi:type="NS2:TCar">
            <GuidCarList xsi:type="xsd:string">6197AFC1-854F-4B2B-9A44-0D59FE3EFC3B</GuidCarList>
            <GuidCar xsi:type="xsd:string">A7A38636-EABC-4EB1-A77F-71902E1EC41C</GuidCar>
            <DateGross xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-11-27T16:59:18.296+07:00</DateGross>
            <DateTare xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">1899-12-30T00:00:00.000+07:00</DateTare>
            <NumCar xsi:type="xsd:string">29483053</NumCar>
            <Capacity xsi:type="xsd:double">71</Capacity>
            <GrossNorm xsi:type="xsd:double">91</GrossNorm>
            <Gross xsi:type="xsd:double">587.44</Gross>
            <Tare xsi:type="xsd:double">23</Tare>
            <GrossLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">529.02</GrossLeft>
            <GrossRight xsi:type="xsd:double">538.81</GrossRight>
            <TareLeft xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareLeft>
            <TareRight xsi:type="xsd:double">0</TareRight>
            <ScaleId xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ScaleId>
            <UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">Оператор</UserName>
            <PhotoList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
         </NS2:TCar>
      </NS1:GetCarsByDateResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Для генерации c# класса использовал [этот генератор](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Десереализовал так :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result));
var dii= (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

В результате всё что внутри TCar == NULL

Что я делаю не так???

Класс в который десереализую:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TestAciSoap
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "href")]
        public string Href { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "return")]
    public class Return
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "arrayType", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
        public string ArrayType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GuidCarList", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]
    public class GuidCarList
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GuidCar")]
    public class GuidCar
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DateGross")]
    public class DateGross
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DateTare")]
    public class DateTare
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "NumCar")]
    public class NumCar
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Capacity")]
    public class Capacity
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GrossNorm")]
    public class GrossNorm
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Gross")]
    public class Gross
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tare")]
    public class Tare
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GrossLeft")]
    public class GrossLeft
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GrossRight")]
    public class GrossRight
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TareLeft")]
    public class TareLeft
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TareRight")]
    public class TareRight
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ScaleId")]
    public class ScaleId
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UserName")]
    public class UserName
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PhotoList")]
    public class PhotoList
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "arrayType", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
        public string ArrayType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TCar", Namespace = "urn:scale_controllerIntf")]
    public class TCar
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GuidCarList")]
        //public GuidCarList GuidCarList { get; set; }
        //[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string GuidCarList { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GuidCar")]
        public GuidCar GuidCar { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateGross")]
        public DateGross DateGross { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateTare")]
        public DateTare DateTare { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumCar")]
        public NumCar NumCar { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Capacity")]
        public Capacity Capacity { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GrossNorm")]
        public GrossNorm GrossNorm { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gross")]
        public Gross Gross { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tare")]
        public Tare Tare { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GrossLeft")]
        public GrossLeft GrossLeft { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GrossRight")]
        public GrossRight GrossRight { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TareLeft")]
        public TareLeft TareLeft { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TareRight")]
        public TareRight TareRight { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ScaleId")]
        public ScaleId ScaleId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UserName")]
        public UserName UserName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PhotoList")]
        public PhotoList PhotoList { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetCarsByDateResponse", Namespace = "urn:scale_controllerIntf-Iscale_controller")]
    public class GetCarsByDateResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "return")]
        public Return Return { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TCar", Namespace = "urn:scale_controllerIntf")]
        public List<TCar> TCar { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NS1", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string NS1 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "NS2", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string NS2 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GetCarsByDateResponse", Namespace = "urn:scale_controllerIntf-Iscale_controller")]
        public GetCarsByDateResponse GetCarsByDateResponse { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "encodingStyle", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string EncodingStyle { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENV", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAPENV { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENC", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAPENC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: Результат десереализации]

Comment: Покажите класс, в который делали десериализацию

Comment: Возьмите SOAP-повский парсер. http://www.cyberforum.ru/web-services-wcf/thread1589878.html например

Comment: Вот похоже https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.3.php

Comment: Если сервис предоставляет wsdl, клиент можно сгенерировать в студии

Comment: При использовании SoapFormatter ошибка: "Ошибка при синтаксическом анализе: отсутствует сборка, связанная с XML-ключом NS1 GetCarsByDateResponse"

Comment: Всё дело в том, что данный сервис написан на Delphi с использованием RPC encode, думаю все беды от этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать вот такое. Получил методом научного тыка.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "TCar", Namespace = "urn:scale_controllerIntf")] 
public class TCar
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GuidCarList", Namespace="")]
    public string GuidCarList { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GuidCar", Namespace="")]
    public string GuidCar { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateGross", Namespace="")]
    public DateTime DateGross { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateTare", Namespace="")]
    public DateTime DateTare { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumCar", Namespace="")]
    public string NumCar { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Capacity", Namespace="")]
    public double Capacity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GrossNorm", Namespace="")]
    public double GrossNorm { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gross", Namespace="")]
    public double Gross { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tare", Namespace="")]
    public double Tare { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GrossLeft", Namespace="")]
    public double GrossLeft { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GrossRight", Namespace="")]
    public double GrossRight { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TareLeft", Namespace="")]
    public double TareLeft { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TareRight", Namespace="")]
    public double TareRight { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ScaleId", Namespace="")]
    public int ScaleId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "UserName", Namespace="")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PhotoList", Namespace="")]
    public string[] PhotoList { get; set; }     
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо! Это решение работает.

Comment: пожалуйста, на здоровье